# Prove that $f(x)\leq\cosh(x)$ $\forall$ $ x\in\mathbb{R^+} $

Tags: integration, derivatives, inequality, exponential-function, alternative-proof

> > Let $ f:\mathbb{R^+}\to(1,+\infty) $ be continuously differentiable function such that 
> >      $ f^{2}(x) -(f^{'})^{2}(x)\geq 1$ $\forall$ $ x\in\mathbb{R^+} $ and $ f(0) =1$.
> >
> > Prove that  $f(x)\leq\cosh(x)$ $\forall$ $ x\in\mathbb{R^+} $

My proof :

Put $f(x)=\cosh(g(x))$ with $g(0)=0$ we get :

$$\cosh^2(g(x))-(g'(x))^2\sinh^2(g(x))\geq 1$$

Or :
$$-(g'(x))^2\sinh^2(g(x))\geq 1-\cosh^2(g(x))$$

Or:

$$-(g'(x))^2\sinh^2(g(x))\geq -\sinh^2(g(x))$$

Or:
$$(g'(x))^2\leq 1$$

Integrating we get :

$$|g(x)|\leq |x|$$

So we get the desired result since $\cosh(x)$ is increasing $\forall$ $ x\in\mathbb{R^+} $

### My question

I'm really curious to see an alternative proof so : Have you another proof ?

Thanks a lot for all your contributions

Comment: If $g(y)=0$ for some $0 < y$, then $-(g'(y))^2\sinh^2(g(y))\geq -\sinh^2(g(y))$ becomes $0 \ge 0$, how can you get $(g'(y))^2 \le 1$?

Comment: Yes I would exclude this case. Thanks.

Comment: I can give you an example in which $g(x)$ is not differentiable at infinitely many points.

Comment: @RiverLi: It is given that $f$ is differentiable and $>1$, which implies that $g$ is differentiable and strictly  positive.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I overlooked $(1, \infty)$ as $[1, \infty)$. Also, I do not know if $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ means $[0, \infty)$ or $(0, \infty)$, since $f(0)=1$, and $0$ belongs to the domain?

Comment: @RiverLi: I understood it as: $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ with $f(0)=1$, and differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ with $f(x)^2 - f'(x)^2 \ge 1$. – Perhaps OP can confirm that, or clarify the assumptions, if necessary.

Comment: @MartinR  Yes. There are several versions: Problem 1: Let $f: [0, \infty) \to [1, \infty)$ be a continuously differentiable function with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) > 1$ for $x > 0$, satisfying $f^2 - (f')^2 \ge 1$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @MartinR I think that the following problem 2 is also true, but $g(x)$ is not differentiable at infinitely many points, and we may not simply take derivative. Problem 2: Let $f: [0,\infty) \to [1, \infty)$ be a continuously differentiable function with $f(0)=1$, satisfying $f^2 - (f')^2 \ge 1 $ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @RiverLi: You are right. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\acosh}{acosh}$

I think your solution is fine. $g(x) = \acosh(f(x))$ is continuous for $x \ge 0$, and differentiable and strictly positive for $x > 0$.  You derived that
$$
 \sinh^2 g(x) (g'(x)^2 - 1) \le 0
$$
so that we can conclude
$$
 g'(x)^2 \le 1 \implies g'(x) \le 1 
$$
for $x > 0$, and $g(x) \le x$ follows.

An alternative approach is to write
$$
 f'(x) \le |f'(x)| \le \sqrt{f^2(x) - 1}
$$
so that for $0 < x < y$
$$
 \int_x^y \frac{f'(t)}{\sqrt{f^2(t) - 1}} \, dt \le \int_x^y 1 \, dt \\
\implies \acosh(f(y)) - \acosh(f(x)) \le y - x \, .
$$
Letting $x \to 0$ we get
$$
\acosh(f(y)) \le y \implies f(y) \le \cosh(y) \, .
$$

---

If suffices to assume that $f:[0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ is continuous with $f(0) = 1$, and that $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ with $f(x)^2 - f'(x)^2 \ge 1$.

Assume that $f(b) > \cosh(b)$ for some $b > 0$. Define
$$
 a = \max \{ x \in [0, c] : f(x) \le \cosh(x) \} \, .
$$
Then $f(a) = \cosh(a)$ and $f(x) > \cosh(x) > 1$ for $a < x \le b$. Now integrate as above to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: (+1) it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0) = 1$ and $f^2 - f'^2 ≥ 1$ we have $f'(0) = 0$
and $\cosh'(x) = 0$, Also $f(0) = cosh(0)$ so it will be enough to prove that $cosh'(x) ≥ f'(x)$ for $x > 0$. It is not so hard you can easily continue this.